# How long data stays in DynamoDB Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to send data from DynamoDB to AWS Lambda, and to configure fault tolerance I am looking into the data retention.

As per AWS docs DDB Stream keeps data for 24 hours. However when we set the Trigger to AWS Lambda, we can set the data retention to 7 days. How is this possible?

> When enabled, DynamoDB Streams captures a time-ordered sequence of
> item-level modifications in a DynamoDB table and durably stores the
> information for up to 24 hours.

[DynamoDB Stream Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/)

> Enabling Trigger and Data Retention during Error

[image]

How can trigger have maximum age to 7 days when the source DDB Stream can only keep data for 24 hours?

Comment: I think its just a default max value available for kinesis stream (7 days). Dynamodb is using 24h instead of 7 days, but the lambda interfaces specifies the default value.